# What is the information in the error code in the nginx error log indicates?

Tags: nginx, connection-timeout, nginx-upstreams

I am seeing upstream timeout error in nginx error logs.

```
**2023/10/30 08:15:55 [error] 5328#5328: *609170 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while sending request to upstream**
```

What does `*609170` indicate? Is it the amount of data downloaded so far before timeout happened?

Comment: I don't know for sure, but it appears to be a sequence number that starts at 1 and probably increments with each successive request handled by the server.